# Simulate random data with correlation

Tags: random, simulation

I would like to simulate some random data e.g. between 0 and 1, but with a given correlation. In other words some data where the correlation between two datasets is e.g. a constant or within a give range of correlations for example a minimum of 0.2 and a maximum of 0.8.

Any tips how to use e.g. RandomReal or another function to create such data?

thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean specifically the result returned by `Correlation` ? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Correlation.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
ClearAll[dist]
dist [rho_] := CopulaDistribution[{"Binormal", rho}, {UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 
    UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]}];

data1 = RandomVariate[dist[-.9], 5000];
ListPlot[data1, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

```
data2 = RandomVariate[dist[.6], 5000];
ListPlot[data2, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 nice.  Checks with `Correlation @@ Transpose[data1]`

Answer (score 5):

```
f[r_?NumberQ,n_Integer]:={First[#],#.{r,Sqrt[1-r^2]}}&/@RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0,1],{n,2}];
```

Produces n pairs of numbers with the correlation r.

Answer (score 1):

Brute Force:

```
 While[! ( .9 < 
      Correlation[ a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10], b = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10  ]] < .91 ) ]
 Correlation[ a, b]
```

> 0.900731

```
 {a, b} // MatrixForm
```

[image]

I expect this breaks down in a hurry for larger sets.