# Generate synthetic multi-dimensional data given its correlation and distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am trying to create a synthetic dataset with 3 columns. I know the correlation between each pair of columns. How do I go about it? A search revealed this [Copula distribution example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77032/204), but it creates 2D data.

I am trying to create a, say, 200 rows with 3 columns, that somewhat looks like:

```
91.9449  94.6969  92.127
87.0049  89.4548  88.0767
82.5728  87.1846  78.6421
91.7373  95.0214  90.4396
81.3041  91.7888  86.5789
```

How do I go about this? The best I have so far is:

```
d1 = NormalDistribution[66, 9.28];
d2 = NormalDistribution[98.66, 5.76];
d3 = NormalDistribution[68.71, 9.57];
jointD = CopulaDistribution[
            {"Multinormal", 1/3}, 
            {d1, d2, d3}]
```

I know that each column has a correlation of around 0.4 with the other.

Comment: Have you seen [`MultinormalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultinormalDistribution.html)? It directly takes a covariance matrix as input.

Comment: @MarcoB I just noticed that after you mention it.  I am trying to understand the syntax.  It seems to only take 2 means but I need 3 means (one for each column)? I wonder if I am comprehending this right.

Comment: It takes however many means you want, just in a list. Try `RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[{1, 2, 3}, IdentityMatrix[3]], 3]` just to see how it might work. In this example I impose zero correlation between variables, each with a mean of 1, 2, or 3, respectively.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you dear sir/madam.  You are more than welcome to provide this as an answer if you wish and if you think this is not a trivial question.

Comment: Glad it helped. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`MultinormalDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultinormalDistribution.html):

```
means = {1, 10, 50};
covariance = {
   {1, 0.1, 0.9},
   {0.1, 1, 0.2},
   {0.9, 0.2, 1}
   };

dist = MultinormalDistribution[means, covariance];
```

You can then get points from the distribution as follows:

```
pts = RandomVariate[dist, 250];
```

Here are pairwise scatter plots to show the relationships between variables:

```
Grid@
 Table[
  ListPlot[pts[[All, {i, j}]], Axes -> False, Frame -> True],
  {i, 3}, {j, 3}
 ]
```

[image: pairwise scatter plots]

Comment: very nice, thank you!  From a pedagogic perspective, your answer defines many learning objectives to a student (such as myself) of statistical distributions.  It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Format[σ[i_]] := Subscript[σ, i];
Format[ρ[i_, j_]] := Subscript[ρ, StringJoin[ToString /@ {i, j}]];
```

Your marginal distributions are

```
d1 = NormalDistribution[66.0625`, 9.284389244512372`];
d2 = NormalDistribution[98.66843971631205`, 5.7644614465554795`];
d3 = NormalDistribution[68.71808510638297`, 9.570687048927134`];
```

The mean vector is

```
μ = First /@ {d1, d2, d3};

ρ[i_, i_] := 1;
ρ[i_, j_] /; j < i := ρ[j, i];
```

The covariance matrix is

```
coVar[n_] := Array[ ρ[#1, #2]*σ[#1]*σ[#2] &, {n, n}];
```

For your example,

```
(Σ = coVar[3]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

For your distributions and with the correlation coefficients all being `0.4` the covariance matrix is

```
(Σv = Σ /. 
     Thread[{ρ[1, 2], ρ[1, 3], ρ[2, 3]} -> 0.4] /.
    Thread[{σ[1], σ[2], σ[3]} -> Last /@ {d1, d2, d3}]) //
 MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
jointD = MultinormalDistribution[μ, Σv];
```

You generate data with [`RandomVariate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate.html)

```
SeedRandom[1234];
(data = RandomVariate[jointD, 10]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]